# Background-image CSS Property not working bootstrap

Tags: css

Encontre este codigo en bootsnip. Estoy intentando que la imagen que tengo en mi ordenador se muestre con este codigo. El codigo funciona bien cuando el url es externo. Cuando le pongo un url interno no responde. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Aqui esta el codigo:

CSS

```
.paymentWrap {
    padding: 50px;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod {
    padding: 40px;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: relative;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod.active {
    outline: none !important;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod.active .method {
    border-color: #4cd264;
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 22px 0px #7b7b7b;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method {
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}


.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.amex {
    background-image: url("img/1.jpg"); ***ESTE NO FUNCIONA***
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.vishwa {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/VkiM7PL.jpg");
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.ez-cash {
    background-image: url("http://www.busbooking.lk/img/carousel/BusBooking.lk_ezCash_offer.png");
}


.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method:hover {
    border-color: #4cd264;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="paymentCont">
    <div class="headingWrap">
        <h3 class="headingTop text-center">Select Your Payment Method</h3>
        <p class="text-center">Created with bootsrap button and using radio button</p>
    </div>
    <div class="paymentWrap">
        <div class="btn-group paymentBtnGroup btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn paymentMethod active">
                                        <div class="method visa"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" checked> 
                                    </label>
            <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                                        <div class="method master-card"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                                    </label>
            <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                                        <div class="method amex"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="options">
                                    </label>
            <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                                            <div class="method vishwa"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                                    </label>
            <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                                        <div class="method ez-cash"></div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                                    </label>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footerNavWrap clearfix">
        <div class="btn btn-success pull-left btn-fyi"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> CONTINUE SHOPPING</div>
        <div class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-fyi">CHECKOUT<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your file exists ? By the way... This is Spanish SO.

Comment: It does! And sorry about that I am using my roomate's computer

Comment: Under your background-image add a z-index with a value like 10 or more. Also, what you can try is to use the image as your website background. If it is not visible maybe the url is incorrect.

Comment: I just tried the z index and it didnt work. The url is correct. I really dont know what else to try... if the code works with a remote url it should work with a local one right?

Comment: I'm trying your code in my computer. But it seems the radio buttons are to little to have an image. And i cant even see external ones. Can you post an image of how your code is looking?

Comment: @LucasDavid tú mismo comentabas que éste es stack overflow en español. Por favor no continúes la conversación en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Si muestra la imagen, lo que tienes que verificar es si la imagen se encuentra en el directorio que la buscas, te dejo imagenes ilustrativas, para que veas de donde llamo a las imagenes en el proyecto, espero te sirva.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.paymentWrap {
 padding: 50px;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup {
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: auto;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod {
 padding: 40px;
 box-shadow: none;
 position: relative;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod.active {
 outline: none !important;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod.active .method {
 border-color: #4cd264;
 outline: none !important;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 22px 0px #7b7b7b;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method {
 position: absolute;
 right: 3px;
 top: 3px;
 bottom: 3px;
 left: 3px;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.visa {
 background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.master-card {
 background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.amex {
 background-image: url("http://www.paymentscardsandmobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Amex-icon.jpg");
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.vishwa {
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/VkiM7PL.jpg");
}

.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.ez-cash {
 background-image: url("http://www.busbooking.lk/img/carousel/BusBooking.lk_ezCash_offer.png");
}


.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method:hover {
 border-color: #4cd264;
 outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="paymentCont">
      <div class="headingWrap">
        <h3 class="headingTop text-center">Select Your Payment Method</h3> 
        <p class="text-center">Created with bootsrap button and using radio button</p>
      </div>
      <div class="paymentWrap">
       <div class="btn-group paymentBtnGroup btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                 <label class="btn paymentMethod active">
                  <div class="method visa"></div>
                     <input type="radio" name="options" checked> 
                 </label>
                 <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                  <div class="method master-card"></div>
                     <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                 </label>
                 <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                  <div class="method amex"></div>
                     <input type="radio" name="options">
                 </label>
                  <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                   <div class="method vishwa"></div>
                     <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                 </label>
                 <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                  <div class="method ez-cash"></div>
                     <input type="radio" name="options"> 
                 </label>
              
             </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="footerNavWrap clearfix">
       <div class="btn btn-success pull-left btn-fyi"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> CONTINUE SHOPPING</div>
       <div class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-fyi">CHECKOUT<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></div>
      </div>
     </div>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahora bien el código, la carpeta imagen debe estar en el mismo lugar donde se encuentra el CSS, si no debes de cambiar la ruta ./img o ../img, depende del nivel que se encuentre el CSS.

Recuerda que si insertas la Imagen desde un CSS, esta debe tener una ruta relativa a el, y no al HTML.

Editado:
Si en el CSS tenemos esta propiedad:

```
.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.amex {
    background-image: url("img/1.jpg"); ***ESTE NO FUNCIONA***
}
```

En la carpeta donde esta ese CSS por ejemplo (**Estilos**), debe estar la carpeta **img** y asi mismo la imagen **1.jpg** asi:

[image: Modo en que los Archivos deben quedar Ubicados]

De tal manera cuando el css busque la imagen la encuentre, si esta carpeta de IMG esta arriba (en otro nivel) te mueves utilizando **..** (2 puntos significa una carpeta atrás), quedando el codigo:

```
.paymentWrap .paymentBtnGroup .paymentMethod .method.amex {
    background-image: url("../img/1.jpg"); ***ESTE NO FUNCIONA***
}
```

Comment: podrias ser un poco mas claro con la respuesta? mira [answer]..

Comment: Grande! Enorme esta solucion, no puedo creer que fuese tan simple! Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: @rudydev90 Me alegro que funcionase aveces nos trabamos en cosas tan sencillas, me pasa mucho jajaja. Si puedes marca mi repuesta como la Solución Gracias :)